# Can a license contain optional or configurable terms?

Tags: licensing

The licenses I am familiar with are typically immutable / static text. They list their terms as they are, and they apply generally.

Is it possible for the license terms to contain configurable or conditional options?

So that when using the license, an author of a work can use it as a skeleton for the essential bits, but still configure certain key use options.

And when another user wants to license the work for use, the terms and options of that license are established within the scope or derived from the work license?

Such options may be allowing commercial or free use, allowing or prohibiting modifications, choosing between open and proprietary, require attribution or not and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The family of [Creative Commons licences](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/) have a variety of terms that can be included or not in the particular licence:

- whether attribution is required
- whether commercial use is permitted
- whether derivative works are permitted
- whether adaptations or derivatives must also be shared under the same licence

But any individual licence is just a selection from among these variations. The licence itself, once selected, is not "configurable."